# Can't create composite roles in Keycloak using Admin REST Api

Tags: json, rest, keycloak

I'm attempting to manage roles and composites programmatically in my Keycloak 6.0.1 system using the Admin REST API. According to the documentation, this is what I want to be using:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/rest-api/index.html#_roles_resource

Right off the bat, my base URL for Keycloak's API seems to be:

https://example.com/auth/admin

instead of `/auth`, as the docs seem to suggest. If I use the base URL specified in the docs I get a 404. I discovered this alternate URL structure by inspecting what the Kubernetes admin page was doing when I manage the installation through my browser.

In any case, I am now successfully creating roles using the `POST /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles` endpoint. Problems begin when I try to add a composite using `POST /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}/composites` with a POST like this:

```
/auth/admin/realms/REDACTED/clients/546052d9-6ba1-483e-93a5-a5fda51505b8/roles/%5ECouponAttemptsLog%25Unowned%25Write/composites
authorization: Bearer REDACTED
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 217
User-Agent: node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Connection: close
Host: REDACTED

{"roles":[{"name":"^CouponAttemptsLog/id%Unowned%Write"},{"name":"^CouponAttemptsLog/code%Unowned%Write"},{"name":"^CouponAttemptsLog/eventId%Unowned%Write"},{"name":"^CouponAttemptsLog/attemptedDate%Unowned%Write"}]}
```

The error message logged by Keycloak is:

```
14:18:02,617 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-4884) Uncaught server error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
```

...and Keycloak returns a 500 response with no text.

As far as I can tell, this matches the expected request shape specified in the Keycloak 6 API documentation, and I'm at a loss for what could be causing this deserialization failure. Just for yuks, I tried sending in a naked JSON array as the body, with no improvement.

What am I doing wrong? I understand that the error from Keycloak means it's trying to convert something to an ArrayList which can't be, but I'm at a loss to figure out what and why.

Answer (score 1):

It wants an array of role objects. Try this:

```
   [
      {
         "name": "^CouponAttemptsLog/id%Unowned%Write"
      },
      {
         "name": "^CouponAttemptsLog/code%Unowned%Write"
      },
      {
         "name": "^CouponAttemptsLog/eventId%Unowned%Write"
      },
      {
         "name": "^CouponAttemptsLog/attemptedDate%Unowned%Write"
      }
   ]
```

Glancing at the code, I think you'll need to include a role id in addition the name...even if the doc says all fields within `RoleRepresentation` are optional.

Comment: I passed in such an array, which you can see in the `POST` excerpt I included. I did also try popping the array out of the `role` object just in case, but that didn't help either.

Comment: You passed the object with a `roles` key, it wants a plain array. Please update your question with the error message you get when you pass in the array in our answer.

Comment: This is not valid JSON. After the initial opening braces (`{`), there should be a key. Instead, the start of an array (`[`) appears. Should the outmost braces be removed?

Comment: @Codo Yup, thank you. The previous version of the answer was a plain array, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved your problem but in my case I need to use both `id` and `name` while assigning roles to composite role. And yes "partial" roles need to be created before assignment to composite role.

```
   [
      {
         "id": UUID of created role
         "name": "^CouponAttemptsLog/id%Unowned%Write"
      }
   ]
```

Flow in my looks like this:

1. In a loop create partial role(s) - Keycloak api return location of new role in headers so you need to call `GET` to obtain role's json
2. Push `{"id": UUID}` to array - or even better `{"id": UUID, "name": name }` or whole role's representation (to call `composites` `id` is enough but in case of service roles you need both
3. Create composite role
4. Call `composites` endpoint